# Access action query fails from VBA call, but successfully executes manually

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, odbc

I have three different INSERT INTO queries in MS Access. The queries are querying ODBC linked tables in the database. All work fine when manually ran from Access. All take less than 1 minute and return between 16,000 and 3,000 records.

When I try to execute the queries from an Access VBA Module, two of the queries work fine, but on one of them the execute statement never finishes running. It does not time out or error out. When I break the code it always hangs at the `CurrentDb.Execute strQRY` line for this particular query.

It has a lot of null fields because it is UNION-ed to another query afterwards. I've tried changing timeout properties and calling the execution statement differently, but nothing helps. The query runs in 10 seconds when manually executed. VBA and SQL posted below:

VBA - Method of execution. Clear all records first and then run the insert query:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM " & strTBL
CurrentDb.Execute strQRY
```

SQL - All Stored in query called:

```
INSERT INTO src_subqry_PDF_Text_Notes
SELECT *
FROM (

     SELECT

        LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.CMPNO,
        Null As VNDNO,
        Null As VNAME,
        Null as NeedXRef,

        Null As BUYER,
        Null As BMNAM,
        LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[PONO#] As PURCH,
        LOGICLIB_INPOL300.[LINE#] As [LINEN],
        LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[PROD#] As PRDNO,
        Null As SDESC,
        Null As DESCP,

        Null As PODDT,
        Null As OREDT,
        Null As PORDT,
        Null As RQ3DT,

        Null As ECOST,
        Null As LNCST,
        Null As ACOST,
        Null as NeedOpenCost,
        Null As PCRCD,

        Null As QUANO,
        Null As QUANR,
        Null as NeedQtyOpenBase,
        Null As UTMES,

        Null As P3QOR,
        Null As P3QRC,
        Null as NeedQtyOpenPURCH,
        Null As ORDUM,

        Null as NeedOrderType,
        'Z' As LNTYP,
        Null As LSTAT,
        Null As PSTAT,
        Null As POTYP,
        Null As P1PAP,  
        Null As PAPV1,
        Null As PAPV2,
        Null As PAPV3,
        Null As PAPV4,
        Null As PA1DT,
        Null As PA2DT,
        Null As PA3DT,
        Null As PA4DT,

        Null As POCST,
        Null As POFOB, 
        Null As SHIPV, 
        Null As CARIR, 
        Null As FGTRM, 
        Null As PPHOA, 
        Null As REQNO,                

        Null As VADD1, 
        Null As VADD2, 
        Null As VADDX,
        Null As VACSZ, 
        Null As VPHOA, 
        Null As VAPGL, 
        Null As VMED1, 
        Null As VTXB1, 

        Null As CNAME, 
        Null As ADDR1, 
        Null As ADDR2, 
        Null As ADDRX, 
        Null As CACSZ,  

        [TXSQ#], 
        TXTDT

    FROM
        LOGICLIB_MFTXL300 
        LEFT JOIN LOGICLIB_INPOL300 ON (LOGICLIB_INPOL300.PURCH = LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[PONO#] AND LOGICLIB_INPOL300.PRDNO = LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[PROD#])

    WHERE
        PURCH IN (SELECT DISTINCT PURCH FROM LOGICLIB_INPOL100 WHERE(PSTAT <> 'Y'))

    )
```

Thank you!

Comment: Edit question to post the code that constructs strQRY.

Comment: strQRY is just the Name of the Access query containing the posted SQL

Comment: You named a query object strQRY? Not very descriptive. Could try DoCmd.OpenQuery and see what warnings are triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working last night. I hope this helps anyone who has a similar issue.

I think the root cause was the `SELECT DISTINCT` clause in the original `WHERE` statement. I still don't know why the query only failed when executed through VBA, but I changed to putting more logic in the `JOIN` instead of in the `WHERE` clause.

```
INSERT INTO src_subqry_PDF_Text_Notes (PURCH, CMPNO, LINEN, PRDNO, LNTYP, [TXSQ#], TXTDT)
    SELECT 
        LOGICLIB_INPOL100.PURCH,
        LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.CMPNO,
        LOGICLIB_INPOL300.[LINE#],
        LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[PROD#],
        'Z' AS LNTYP,
        LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[TXSQ#], 
        LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.TXTDT
    FROM
        ((LOGICLIB_INPOL100
        LEFT JOIN LOGICLIB_INPOL300 ON (LOGICLIB_INPOL100.PURCH = LOGICLIB_INPOL300.PURCH AND LOGICLIB_INPOL100.CMPNO = LOGICLIB_INPOL300.CMPNO))
        LEFT JOIN LOGICLIB_MFTXL300 ON (LOGICLIB_INPOL300.PURCH = LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[PONO#] AND LOGICLIB_INPOL300.PRDNO = LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[PROD#] AND LOGICLIB_INPOL300.CMPNO = LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.CMPNO))
    WHERE
        LOGICLIB_INPOL100.PSTAT <> 'Y' AND LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[TXSQ#] > 1
```

Thanks June7 for the simplifying the SQL to explicit fields for ease of reading online.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you explicitly reference the 7 fields to populate and remove all the Null fields. Don't need the `SELECT * FROM`

```
INSERT INTO src_subqry_PDF_Text_Notes (CMPNO, PURCH, LINEN, PRDNO, LNTYP, [TXSQ#], TXTDT)
    SELECT
        LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.CMPNO,
        LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[PONO#],
        LOGICLIB_INPOL300.[LINE#],
        LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[PROD#],
        'Z' AS LNTYP,
        [TXSQ#], 
        TXTDT
    FROM
        LOGICLIB_MFTXL300 
        LEFT JOIN LOGICLIB_INPOL300 ON (LOGICLIB_INPOL300.PURCH = LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[PONO#] AND LOGICLIB_INPOL300.PRDNO = LOGICLIB_MFTXL300.[PROD#])
    WHERE
        PURCH IN (SELECT DISTINCT PURCH FROM LOGICLIB_INPOL100 WHERE PSTAT <> 'Y')
```

Advise not to use punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in names. Better would be PONONum or PONO_NUM. All uppercase is also not preferred as it is harder to read.

Comment: The code is still hanging on the execute line after simplifying the SQL to the explicit fields.